# Node.js crypto module

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, node-crypto

I am trying to implement encryption in node.js using the crypto module. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
var SECRET_KEY = "RANDOMKEY";
var crypto = require("crypto");
var MD5 = crypto.createHash("MD5");
MD5.update(SECRET_KEY, 'ucs2');
var hash = MD5.digest('binary');


var key = new Buffer(hash, 'binary');
var keyStart = new Buffer(8, 'binary');
key.copy(keyStart, 0, 0, 8);


var valueToEncrypt = new Buffer('password', 'utf-8').toString('binary');
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc',keyStart, keyStart);
var cryptedPassword = cipher.update(valueToEncrypt, 'binary', 'base64');

cryptedPassword+= cipher.final('base64');

console.log(cryptedPassword);gives---> r4xhQ8T87z2FFkLOxkcnGg==
```

What I should be getting back is ***r4xhQ8T87z26w30I1vr9kA==***
I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: How are you generating the expected value? Why are you only hashing the first 8 bytes of your secret key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it is encrypting properly, your expected value just includes a `"\r\n"` after the password, which this example code does not provide.

`"r4xhQ8T87z2FFkLOxkcnGg=="` decrypts to `"password"` but `"r4xhQ8T87z26w30I1vr9kA=="` decrypts to `"password\r\n"`.

With that out of the way, you have gone a bit crazy with encodings. It is simpler to keep everything as a `Buffer`.

```
var SECRET_KEY = "RANDOMKEY";
var crypto = require("crypto");

var MD5 = crypto.createHash("MD5");
MD5.update(SECRET_KEY, 'ucs2');
var keyStart = MD5.digest().slice(0, 8);

var valueToEncrypt = 'password\r\n';
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', keyStart, keyStart);
var cryptedPassword = cipher.update(valueToEncrypt, 'utf8', 'base64') +
    cipher.final('base64');

console.log(cryptedPassword);
```

Comment: Thanks so much.This works!! :-) I am still trying to get to grisps with encoding.